# Amplitude Amplification applied to HHL Algorithm

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, cirq, hhl-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I’m trying to understand and implement the amplitude amplification algorithm described in the [HHL paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3171.pdf). I’m using the [cirq implementation of the HHL algorithm](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/examples/hhl.py) as my starting point.

I have a couple of doubts with regard to this:

1. The paper says the number of times the amplitude amplification procedure has to be applied to the HHL algorithm is [image] and [image].

I’m unsure about how to calculate p˜ with regard to the cirq implementation.
I’m also unclear as to how to find the functions f and g and the parameter λ˜. Could someone please help me understand this?

2. With regard to the exact procedure to be used for amplitude amplification, the paper defines two new operators [image] and [image]

From what I understand, I need to loop over the HHL subroutine constantly applying an operator **P = - R<sub>succ</sub>R<sub>init</sub>** to it.

Could someone please explain how R<sub>succ</sub> and R<sub>init</sub> are described with respect to the cirq code? Can the P operator be expressed as another oracle?